# Dealing with next line character in C

Tags: c

I have written a program to check if two given strings are palindromes.

It works fine but the test cases **sometimes** include a new line char appended at the end of the string and need that to be ignored.
For example:

Two passed strings are:

```
india\n
aidni
```

and response should be  that Yes, these are palindromes.

My code looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arr1[100];
    char arr2[100];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int len1 = 0, len2 = 0;

    scanf("%s", arr1);
    scanf("%s", arr2);

    while (arr1[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    len1 = i;

    while (arr2[j] != '\0')
        j++;
    len2 = j;

    if (i != j) {
        printf("%s", "no");
        return 0;
    } else {
        int count = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < len1; i++)
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[len1-i-1])
                count++;

        if (count == len1)
            printf("%s", "yes");
        else
            printf("%s", "no");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives output "yes" for `india` and `aidni` but no for `india\n` and `aidni`.

Comment: Did you tried: _scanf("%s\n", arr1);_?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: Yes, that along does not work with the implementation I have.

Comment: @CareyGregory that would *definitely* append a `newline`.

Comment: @SeanBright: No it does not. Try adding \n at end of India and then press enter

Comment: @simikaur: Are you adding the literal characters `'\', 'n'` in the string? That isn't a newline character. It's 2 characters.

Comment: @SeanBright: Never used C so not aware of its inbuilt functions.Will use that now :)

Comment: @simi kaur Does the code have the characters `'\'` and `'n'` in the file or does your example file have a true `'\n'`?

Comment: @SeanBright: The test case that I need to pass is : india\n
daini . This fails with current code.

Comment: @simikaur: Just to clarify, could you print the value of `arr1` and `arr2` and tell us exactly what they hold? Like if you did `printf("'%s'    '%s'\n", arr1, arr2);`

Comment: @BillLynch:  The test case that I need to pass is : india\n daini . This fails with current code I have. I understand that becomes 2 added characters but that is what it looks like in test case as well and they expect the code to pass that.

Comment: @simikaur If you are literally passing \n in input then it should not pass ideally as then it would not be a palindrome

Comment: @BillLynch: if arr1 holds the value india  and arr2 holds the value aidni ,code works. Now, In test case, they expect the code to give positive results for india\n daini which this code fails.

Comment: @simi kaur The `'\'` and `'n'` in your assignment is not the 2 characters but one, a simple <Enter> or `'\n'`.  Removed them from your file and just have line feed between them.

Comment: @mSatyam: I completely understand that but stuck with these test cases

Comment: @simikaur but whosoever has given you this job and specified that a \n in input should be considered as newline and not two separate characters then its a different thing all together.

Comment: I think you should look up "escape characters" as there is some confusion over whether `\n` is two characters text or an escaped newline. If you type that in as two characters, they are two characters and the palindrome will fail. If it is meant to represent a single char newline, that must be filtered out by the algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### So there's a significant amount of confusion.

It wasn't originally clear if the `\n` in your input was one character, or two. It sounds like it's two.

#### What should we do?

So, what we need to do, is take two strings as input, apply a filter to those strings to remove characters that we are **not** interested in. And then do our palindrome test.

#### How might we do this?

I've added a call to a new function called `cleanup()`. This function will remove any sequence of a backslash followed by an n from the given string. I've also cleaned up the end code by just reversing one of the strings, and then seeing if they are identical.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void cleanup(char *s) {
    char *source = s;
    char *destination = s;

    while (*source != '\0')
        if (source[0] == '\\' && source[1] == 'n')
            source += 2;
        else
            *destination++ = *source++;
    *destination = '\0';
}

void reverse(char *s) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<len/2; ++i) {
        char temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[len - i - 1];
        s[len - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char arr1[100];
    char arr2[100];

    scanf("%s", arr1);
    scanf("%s", arr2);

    cleanup(arr1);
    cleanup(arr2);
    reverse(arr2);

    if (strcmp(arr1, arr2) == 0)
        printf("Yes\n");
    else
        printf("No!\n");
}
```

When run:

```
[3:28pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./orange 
india\n aidni
Yes
[3:28pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./orange
ind\nia aidn\ni
Yes
[3:29pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./orange
blue green
No!
```

Comment: I think we all know that there will not really be a literal `'\n'` involved, right?

Comment: @SeanBright: My confusion atleast was if the character in the input was `"\n"` or `"\\n"`.

Comment: Looks good - although I still suspect OP test data is supposed to be `'\n'` and not `'\\'`, `'n'`.

Answer (score -1):

Not the most efficient solution but you could iterate through the strings, check for the newline character, and remove it before running your comparison code.

Comment: `scanf("%s", arr1);` does not save a `'\n` into `arr1`

Comment: How is that relevant?  He stated that sometimes the string **will**  have a '\n' so I'm assuming this code will be used in another context besides the one given above.

Comment: The `"%s"` will not save `'\n'` into `arr1`.  So `arr1` does not have any `'\n'` in it to compare.  It does not make a difference what OP types. `scanf("%s", arr1);` does not save any white-space including `'\n'`.

Comment: I know that, but he must have a test case where he is not using scanf since he stated "test cases sometimes include a new line char appended at the end of the string and need that to be ignored."  Otherwise I would agree with you.